# Why is that find_customer_by_name function only search the first customer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example of customers that I want to find from my list:

```
{'Customers': [
    {"Customer's ID": '001', "Customer's Name": 'dor', "Customer's City": 'london', "Customer's age": '26'}, 
    {"Customer's ID": '002', "Customer's Name": 'John Cena', "Customer's City": 'New York', "Customer's age": '45'},
    {"Customer's ID": '003', "Customer's Name": 'Tony Stark', "Customer's City": 'Holywood', "Customer's age": '39'}
]}
```

My code from Customers module to handle the customers system:

```
    def find_customer_by_name(customer_name, customers_library):

    """
    A search function that search customer in library by his name
    :param customer_name: Customer's name'
    :param customers_library: a dict with all customers in the library
    """

    customers_temp_library = copy.deepcopy(customers_library)
    if customer_name in customers_temp_library["Customers"][0]["Customer's Name"]:
        return f"{customer_name} is in the customers library list"
```

The code in main:

```
    if identifier == '3':  # Choosing to find customer (by name)
       print("Enter customer's name you would like to find: ")
       customer_name = input()
       print(find_customer_by_name(customer_name, customers_library))
```

Comment: Because you're only searching `customers_temp_library["Customers"][0]`, instead of searching _every_ element of `customers_temp_library["Customers"]`, which you should be doing using a loop

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy thank you for helping,
I tried to run the program with customers_temp_library["Customers"]
but, it returns me None so it still can not find the name I need

Comment: Why are you creating a copy of the dictionary instead of looping over the original one ? There is no reason to as you are not doing any modifications.

Comment: I really don't know... I was trying to avoid the treading/trampling of the existing dictionary I have. I will take your advice though, how would you do it? @Programmer

Comment: @dorbtz as long as you don't modify the dictionary, you can simply use the original one. If you need to modify the dictionary but want to preserve the original one, then `copy.deepcopy` is right. Note though that it can only copy builtin types, not custom classes (even if they are from a standard library module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not using the iteration process to check all records, the following modification uses the loop to check all records for provided customer name

```
def find_customer_by_name(customer_name, customers_library):

    """
    A search function that search customer in library by his name
    :param customer_name: Customer's name'
    :param customers_library: a dict with all customers in the library
    """

    customers_temp_library = copy.deepcopy(customers_library)
    for i in range(len(customers_temp_library["Customers"])):
        if customer_name in customers_temp_library["Customers"][i]["Customer's Name"]:
            return f"{customer_name} is in the customers library list"
```

Also a optimized form of the code can be following by removing copy as you are not modifying the data so its safe to only iterate the collection and check your required name

```
data = {'Customers': [{"Customer's ID": '001', "Customer's Name": 'dor', "Customer's City": 'london', "Customer's age": '26'}, {"Customer's ID": '002', "Customer's Name": 'John Cena', "Customer's City": 'New York', "Customer's age": '45'},{"Customer's ID": '003', "Customer's Name": 'Tony Stark', "Customer's City": 'Holywood', "Customer's age": '39'}]}

def find_customer_by_name(customer_name, customers_library):

    """
    A search function that search customer in library by his name
    :param customer_name: Customer's name'
    :param customers_library: a dict with all customers in the library
    """

    for customer in customers_library["Customers"]:
        if customer_name == customer["Customer's Name"]:
            return f"{customer_name} is in the customers library list"
    
    return f"{customer_name} is not in the list"

test = ['Tony Stark', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'John Cena']
for name in test:
    print(find_customer_by_name(name, data))
```

**Output is following**

[image]

Comment: thank you very much!, it solve my problem.
If I want to display all the details that I have on the person?
example: if you search Tony Stark you will receive all the details about him from the list